# Tkmacosx "WARNING: Appearance colours are not supported"

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button, tkinter-macos

I'm recieving this message in the shell each time I run my Tkinter program:

```
WARNING: Appearance colours are not either supported with the current tkinter or the colors doesn't exist on this Mac.
```

[image: Example]

However, the colours work and my button looks fine:

```
roll=Button(window, text="Roll the Dice", background="red", fg="white", activebackground='#00FF00',font=("Calibri",(30)), width =180, height = 55, borderless=1)
```

It isn't an error though...

Thanks

Comment: Hi Pesto, it is just a warning and should not affect anything except the dynamic appearance change (dark/light) that will not work with the tkmacosx button maybe even with the main Tkinter window. Refer to this [issue](https://github.com/Saadmairaj/tkmacosx/issues/20) to know more.